# get results from google maps intent

Tags: android, google-maps

in my android application I want the user will be able to choose some location and to get this location back to the application code.
something like startActivityForResults.

Does it's possible?

I know that it is possible with all the google service sdk and all of this,
but I want to use only the content intent, like described here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#overview

and here (in the maps section):
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

thanks a lot.

Comment: I cannot really understand why such simple things doesn't have a simple solution in Android. I've just found that `PlacePicker` is also deprecated and removed from Places SDK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement for an Android device to have an app that does what you want. There is no standard `Intent` structure for this, either.

Comment: why there is no requirement? for example i want him to choose a place for check the weather or something like that.. maybe to choose his city. i don't know why you decided it, it looks fine for me. i just want to know how to do that.

Comment: @user2671057: "why there is norequirrment?" -- you would have to ask Google. "i want him to choose a place for check the weather or something like that.. maybe to choose his city" -- you are welcome to write your own activity for that, using one of the available mapping APIs for Android.